# Was it really necessary to release Santana's convict?

Tags: plot-explanation, riddick

When Santana's ship lands on the planet in *Riddick* (2013) he orders a transported convict to be released, explaining that this will save them 60 kilograms with which the ship would be unable to lift up.

Is this a true problem or just a *licentia poetica* / cut-over scene / story dramatisation (to show how Riddick's sorrow channels into fury and to underline Santana's cruelty)?

I find it hard to believe that:

- Santana became aware of this problem only after landing (or we can assume that he knew it earlier, but preferred Riddick over that convict, due to bounty),
- Santana knew this, but Riddick didn't (since he ordered two teams to leave in one ship),
- a single woman / 60 kilograms makes any difference for a huge space ship.

Is there anything that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There is an "In Plot" reason, and an "Out of Plot" reason.*

The In Plot reason is that Santana "... was getting attached to her". Apparently, he wanted to remain unattached. Please look at this clip.

The Out of Plot reason is that Keri Hilson (playing The Convict) auditioned for the role of Dahl, and did not get it. But she was so good that she was [written into the script](https://thesource.com/2013/09/06/exclusive-keri-hilson-talks-starring-in-riddick-and-her-new-album/). Here's an extract from the link:

> Hilson: Well, I auditioned for a role, a different role; the role of Dahl. And they went with Katee Sackhoff; I’m super excited they did. However, Vin Diesel and David Twohy loved my audition and…it came down to me and Katee and they didn’t want to lose me in the film and they wrote me into the script. So the character that you saw was written specifically for me and that was really cool ...

Answer (score 6):

This question is unanswerable unless it was specifically stated in the film. Weight and balance are critical for modern aircraft and spacecraft. And, small aircraft have crashed (rather famously) due to weight and balance not being considered or taken seriously. But, we can only speculate about advanced technology from a possible future. In the movie, no further explanation regarding the maximum takeoff weight of the ship is given.

Answer (score -3):

Santana said nub Luna we were overloaded. It means of 7 crew + 1 prisoner is already that it. How to intrrplanetary fly with no enough seats or any place for   hibernation with caught Riddick? Delete cheap prisoner - cocky chief thought to catch him easy without crew loss ))

Comment: Hi Valdis, you may want to take the [tour].